# Is there a way in which you can code to record files which give a ParserError?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a bunch of CSV files which need to be worked through. Each file should contain a set number of tables, which hold information. I am using a code to extract the tables, assign them as dataframes, and join them all when exported.

[FILE FORMAT WITH MULTIPLE TABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpmiA.png)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 0, nrows = 1, usecols [1 , 2,  3])
df1.columns = ‘TABLE1_’ + df1.columns
df2 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 2, nrows = 1, usecols [1, 2, 3])
df2.columns = ‘TABLE2_’ + df2.columns
df3 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 4, nrows = 1, usecols [1, 2, 3])
df3.columns = ‘TABLE3_’ + df3.columns
df4 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 6, nrows = 1, usecols [1, 2, 3])
df4.columns = ‘TABLE4_’ + df4.columns

df5 = df1.join([df2, df3, df4])
df5.to_csv(“file_output.csv”, sep = ’,’, encoding = ‘utf-8’, header = True, index = False)
```

However, some of the files have not exported from the main database properly, and as such are missing some of the tables within. This leads to an error when running the code;

> ParserError: Passed header=n, found only n lines in file

I am currently trying to brainstorm ideas as to how we could tackle this particular issue. One of the ways I have considered is to write a condition whereby if the error is raised, instead of stopping the code it would make a record of the file in a text document and then continue. However, I am unfamiliar with how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
def process_file(file_path):
try:
   df1 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 0, nrows = 1, usecols [1 , 2,  3])
   df1.columns = ‘TABLE1_’ + df1.columns
   df2 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 2, nrows = 1, usecols [1, 2, 3])
   df2.columns = ‘TABLE2_’ + df2.columns
  df3 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 4, nrows = 1, usecols [1, 2, 3])
  df3.columns = ‘TABLE3_’ + df3.columns
  df4 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 6, nrows = 1, usecols [1, 2, 3])
 df4.columns = ‘TABLE4_’ + df4.columns

  df5 = df1.join([df2, df3, df4])
  df5.to_csv(“file_output.csv”, sep = ’,’, encoding = ‘utf-8’, header = True, index = False)
except pd.errors.ParserError:
   
    with open('error_log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f'Error processing file: {file_path}\n')


     file_list = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv']

    for file in file_list:
   process_file(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Try Except block to catch the errors. Code below catches all errors and records the error and associated filename in a List, which you could print or write to a file. If useful, the process could be put into a Loop to process all the files in a List.

```
import pandas as pd

bad_files = []

def load_file(df, filename, _sep = None, _encoding = None, _header = None, _nrows = None, _usecols = None):
    try:
        print(_header, _nrows, _usecols)
        df=pd.read_csv(filename, sep= _sep, encoding = _encoding, header = _header, nrows = _nrows, usecols = _usecols)
    except Exception as e:
        bad_files.append(f"{filename}  {e}")

df1 = pd.DataFrame()   #created empty dataframe 
load_file(df1, "file1.csv", _sep='\t', _encoding = 'utf-16', _header = 0, _nrows = 1, _usecols = [1, 2, 3])
#and so on

print(bad_files)
```